# URL Formatting in TextView

Tags: android, url, hyperlink, textview

So in my API the user has the urls in the format of `[[www.google.com Google]]` where `Google` would then link to the url. I've been trying to figure out how to write this for a while but can't figure out how to do it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @limonik I've tried `replaceAll` making it a HTML link but what I'm then getting is `<a href="www.google.com Google">www.google.com Google</a>` which I obviously don't want

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try on ClickSpan.

```
try {
        String spannableText = getString(
                R.string.y);
        termsOfService.setText(spannableText);
        int i1 = string.indexOf(spannableText);
        int i2 = i1 + spannableText.length();
        if (i1 > 0 && i2 > 0) {
            Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(string);
            ClickSpan clickableSpan = new ClickSpan(getActivity());
            wordToSpan.setSpan(clickableSpan, i1, i2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            termsOfService.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            termsOfService.setText(wordToSpan);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex != null)
            ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

References are on: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html
Good luck.

Comment: The formatting it's coming out is `<a href="www.google.com Google">www.google.com Google</a>` will `ClickSpan` help with this issue?